# URL not changing consistently in React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reach-router

I'm getting odd behavior using `@reach/router`. My aim is to have a page with tabs. When I click on a tab the url changes and the page changes (though it doesn't reload the whole page). I've been using `chakra ui` since it makes the theme making easier for me.

The behavior I get is odd. Sometimes the URL changes as I switch between tabs. It works great. Then sometimes the URL doesn't change, even though I've switched tabs.

My project is located [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reach-router-example-forked-ydcqz?file=/src/components/ConceptTabs.js:0-1471)

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Link } from "@reach/router";

import {
  Tab,
  Tabs,
  TabList,
  TabPanel,
  TabPanels,
  useColorModeValue
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Somatic from "../pages/somatic";
import Ef from "../pages/executive_functions_coaching";
import Intro from "../pages/home";

function ConceptTabs(props) {

  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(0);
  

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs
        size="lg"
        isFitted
        variant="soft-rounded"
        colorScheme="yellow"
        onChange={(index) => {
          setTabIndex(index);
        }}
      >
        <TabList>
          <Tab>
            <Link to="/">
              Tab1
            </Link>
          </Tab>
          <Tab>
            <Link to="/executive_functions_coaching/">
              Tab2
            </Link>
          </Tab>
          <Tab>
            <Link to="/somatics/">
             Tab3
            </Link>
          </Tab>
        </TabList>
        <TabPanels p="2rem">
          <TabPanel>
            <Router>
            <Intro path='/' />
            </Router>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <Router>
            <Ef path='/executive_functions_coaching/' />
            </Router>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <Router>
            <Somatic path='/somatics/' />
            </ Router>
          </TabPanel>
        </TabPanels>
      </Tabs>
    </>
  );
}

export default ConceptTabs;
```

I've tried to use `<NavLink>` but had similar issues.
I'm quite new to routing, but I've gotten this to work without the tabs. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the router to work with tabs?

Comment: remove the <Router> <Router />....what happens then

Comment: Thanks @KeatonBenning... it gets worse. more inconsistent with changing the urls

Comment: Your linked codesandbox doesn't run, it seems to be missing files. Can you edit it to fix the issues and report back when you've a *running* CSB for us to inspect? Based on what I see above, you've entirely way too many routers... you typically only need one wrapping the entire app to provide any routing context. I'm sure it's no different in `reach-router`, a cousin library to `react-router`.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention @DrewReese. I had edited it earlier but it did not save.  I just did again and simplified it. it's working now on my end. Hopefully the file saved. The links are still problematic, but the sandbox should run without error

Comment: Also - @DrewReese I had tried a single router, but I did not know to make it work with the tabs. The Tab feature I'm using surrounds the content of each page, so I wasn't able to put the router around the different pages in the Tabs. I was able to put a router in the index.js but it still did not work well with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems odd that you are mixing `reach-router` and `react-router-dom`, it's successor, but the root of your issue with the tabs is because each `Tab` component is rendering a `Link` but the entire tab isn't responsible for navigation.

[image]

Only the text part in the middle of each tab/button is the *actual* link, so the navigation only works if you precisely click on the text part of each tab that is the link.

To resolve you can render each `Tab` component ***as*** a `Link` component.

[The `as` prop and custom component](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/layout/box#as-prop)

```
<TabList>
  <Tab as={Link} to="/">
      tab1
  </Tab>
  <Tab as={Link} to="/executive_functions_coaching/">
    tab
  </Tab>
  <Tab as={Link} to="/somatics/">
    tab3
  </Tab>
</TabList>
```

[image: Edit url-not-changing-consistently-in-react-router]

Answer (score 2):

See as following 2 screenshots.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, 'a' tag is in a 'button' tag.
Real size of "a" is very small.
If you might click tab1, it is occured by button.
So, Please, Drew Reese's answer is fit you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to add `onClick={()=>history.push('/route')}` on your tabs.

Here is how to initialize `history`:

```js
improt { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
// inside your component:
history = useHistory();
```